# Function which will fire off a specific template depending on which element is selected

Tags: javascript

I have this function which will fire off a specific template depending on which element is selected. However, with the way it is, I'd have to update the JavaScript and the HTML when a new element is added. What I'd like is to have the function scale up to as many HTML elements one would add.

So far I have figured out if I do this:

```
 function templateLoader(e) {
        var doc = document,
            body = doc.getElementsByTagName('body'),
            event = EventUtility.getEvent(e),
            target = EventUtility.getTarget(event),
            overlay = $('#overlay');

        console.dir(event.currentTarget);

        if (target !== event.currentTarget) {

            switch(target.id){
                case '1':
               $.get('../../../templates/index.html',function(template) {
                 modal.append(Mustache.render($(template).filter('#templateID').html()))
                 modal.listview("refresh");
                 });
                break;

                case '2':
                alert(target.title);
                break;

                case '3':
                alert(target.title);
                break;

                case '4':
                alert(target.title);
                break;

                case '5':
                alert(target.title);
                break;
            }
        }

        EventUtility.stopPropagation(event);

    }

    EventUtility.addHandler(flimFlam, 'click', templateLoader);

});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="Container" class="container">
      <div id="1" title="belief" class="list mix category-1 image-holder" data-myorder="1"><img class="crest" src="public/images/belief.svg" alt="belief"></div>
       <div id="2" title="integrity" class="list mix category-1 image-holder" data-myorder="2"><img class="crest" src="public/images/integrity.svg" alt="integrity"></div>

       <div id="3" title="respect" class="list mix category-1 image-holder" data-myorder="3"><img class="crest" src="public/images/respect.svg" alt="respect"></div>

       <div id="4" title="trust" class="list mix category-2 image-holder" data-myorder="4"><img class="crest" src="public/images/trust.svg" alt="trust"></div>

       <div id="5" title="humility" class="list mix category-1 image-holder" data-myorder="5"><img class="crest" src="public/images/humility.svg" alt="humility"></div>
</div>
```

But of course that depends on me going int there and adding newer `case` conditions when needed. I know I'll have to go into the files anyway when the HTML is added. But I wanted a way to have the JS ready for any amount of cases.

I began with something like this:

```
 for (var i = 0, l = event.target.length; i < l; i++) {
                console.log(target.id[i]);
            };
```

Comment: Can you give us some more context on how this function will get used? Maybe an example function call. This code also looks incomplete, as you are just calling `alert`. Is this something where the user clicks on an element, renders a template, and the results are put into another element?

Comment: Hey Greg, I updated the code above; inserted what I imagined would go there. This solution I am sure would work, but like I said, that would result it me having to update the `HTML` and the `JS`. I am imagining it being scalable. Which is why I thought a `loop` would be a starting point. Hope that helps.

Comment: I've edited out the "UPDATE" part, as we prefer seamless edits; also in order to keep the received answer in sync with your edit I had to edit that `case 1` snippet into the answer; for future posts, please make sure you post your *real, actual code* from the start - stripping context for a Code Review question, amounts to shooting yourself in the foot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
body = doc.getElementsByTagName('body'),
```

There's a shorter `document.body`. But then, `body` isn't even being used in the function. So you probably have to remove it.

```
console.dir(event.currentTarget);
alert(target.title);
```

I suggest you don't pepper your code with `console.*` and `alert` to view values. Take advantage of the browser's debugger, and use breakpoints. Not only can you view the variable, you can also view surrounding variables, enclosing scopes and more.

```
switch(target.id){
```

First, I wouldn't use `id`. `id` is supposed to be unique in the page. Use it if you're absolutely sure that the element is the only one in the page with that `id`. This can get real messy when you discover that your HTML needs to be in multiple places, but contain the same structure and/or content.

But then, I notice you use `data-*` attributes. Use that instead of `id`. It's designed for that purpose, carry data in markup.

```
 case '1':
$.get('../../../templates/index.html',function(template) {
  modal.append(Mustache.render($(template).filter('#templateID').html()))
  modal.listview("refresh");
  });

 break;

 case '2':
 alert(target.title);
 break;

 case '3':
 alert(target.title);
 break;

 case '4':
 alert(target.title);
 break;

 case '5':
 alert(target.title);
 break;
```

It doesn't have a default. `switch` is also a bit clunky. And I usually avoid `switch` because failing to add a `break` where needed will cause your code to run down an unexpected path.

The following would be a better way to model it:

```
// An operations object, with key as the id, and function as value
var operations = {
  '1': function(){
    $.get('../../../templates/index.html',function(template) {
      modal.append(Mustache.render($(template).filter('#templateID').html()))
      modal.listview("refresh");
      });
  },
  '2': function(){
    alert(target.title);
  },
  // and so on
}

if(typeof operations[target.id] === 'function') operations[target.id].call(null);
```

Comment: Hey thanks Joseph, I think I understand, but it still seems a bit vague to me, perhaps because of the `noop` function?!